# Ruby: How can I convert this array into this hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of arrays. Each item in the array contains three strings: a leg count, an animal and a sound.

```
a = [ ['4', 'dog', 'woof'] , ['4', 'cow', 'moo'], ['2', 'human', 'yo'] , ['2', 'yeti', 'wrarghh'] ]
```

I want to turn the array into this hash:

```
{ 
  '2' => [ { 'human' => 'yo' }, { 'yeti' => 'wrarghh'} ],
  '4' => [ { 'dog' => 'woof' }, { 'cow' => 'moo'} ]
}
```

I thought reduce would be the way to go but I'm not having much luck. My current stab looks like:

```
a.reduce({}) do |acc, item|
             acc[item.first] = [] unless acc.key? item.first
             acc[item.first] << { item[1] => item[2] }
           end
```

But it gets an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `key?' for [{"dog"=>"woof"}]:Array
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: One way `a.group_by { |key, *_| key  }.transform_values { |arr| arr.map { |_, k, v| { k => v } } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a.each_with_object({}) { |(kout, kin, val), h| (h[kout] ||= []) << { kin => val } }
  #=> {"4"=>[{"dog"=>"woof"}, {"cow"=>"moo"}], "2"=>[{"man"=>"yo"}, {"yeti"=>"wrarghh"}]}
```

We have

```
enum = a.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["4", "dog", "woof"], ["4", "cow", "moo"], ["2", "man", "yo"],
  #                  ["2", "yeti", "wrarghh"]]:each_with_object({})>
```

The first value is generated by this enumerator and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned values:

```
(kout, kin, val), h = enum.next
  #=> [["4", "dog", "woof"], {}]
```

which is decomposed as follows.

```
kout
  #=> "4"
kin
  #=> "dog"
val
  #=> "woof"
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is therefore

```
(h[kout] ||= []) << { kin => val }
  #=> (h[kout] = h[kout] || []) << { "dog" => "wolf" }
  #=> (h["4"] = h["4"] || []) << { "dog" => "wolf" }
  #=> (h["4"] = nil ||= []) << { "dog" => "wolf" }
  #=> (h["4"] = []) << { "dog" => "wolf" }
  #=> [] << { "dog" => "wolf" }
  #=> [{ "dog" => "wolf" }]
```

`h["4"] || [] #=> []` since `h` has no key `"4"` and therefore `h["4"] #=> nil`.

The next value of `enum` is passed to the block and the calculations are repeated.

```
(kout, kin, val), h = enum.next
  #=> [["4", "cow", "moo"], {"4"=>[{"dog"=>"woof"}]}]
kout
  #=> "4"
kin
  #=> "cow"
val
  #=> "moo"
h #=> {"4"=>[{"dog"=>"woof"}]}

(h[kout] ||= []) << { kin => val }
  #=> (h[kout] = h[kout] || []) << { "cow" => "moo" }
  #=> (h["4"] = h["4"] || []) << { "cow" => "moo" }
  #=> (h["4"] = [{"dog"=>"woof"}] ||= []) << { "cow" => "moo" }
  #=> (h["4"] = [{"dog"=>"woof"}]) << { "cow" => "moo" }
  #=> [{"dog"=>"woof"}] << { "cow" => "moo" }
  #=> [{ "dog" => "wolf" }, { "cow" => "moo" }]
```

This time `h["4"] || [] #=> [{ "dog" => "wolf" }]` because `h` now has a key `"4"` with a truthy value (`[{ "dog" => "wolf" }]`).

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Or `each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [ ] })` if you want to skip the `(h[kout] ||= [ ])` and don't mind your result having a default proc.

Comment: @muistooshort, I actually started writing it the way you suggest but figured that would require a somewhat lengthy explanation so used the old-fashioned way (which I tend to prefer anyway). Do you have a preference yourself? I'll explain `(h[kout] ||= [])`.

Comment: I use both forms depending on no real criteria other than which seems more natural at the time.

Comment: @muistooshort, ha! Me too.

Comment: Your explanations are appreciated BTW. Much nicer than just throwing down some code.

Answer (score 2):

You way works, but, for [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), the return value (ie, the last line) of the block becomes the next value for (in this case) `acc`, so all you need to change is:

```
a.reduce({}) do |acc, item|
  acc[item.first] = [] unless acc.key? item.first
  acc[item.first] << { item[1] => item[2] }

  acc # just add this line
end
```

Since the return value for [`Array#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) is the array itself, the second iteration gave `acc` as the array for the first element. There are, of course, lots of ways to do this, some arguably cleaner, but I find it's useful to know where I went wrong when something I think should work doesn't.

Comment: You can avoid that pesky last line by using `each_with_object` rather than `reduce` and can simplify a little by replacing `item` with`(key, value)` in the block variables.

Comment: @Cary Yeah, as mentioned, there are other ways to do this, other than `reduce`, but since they posted code they thought should work, and it didn't, thought it would be helpful to explain to them why their code didn't work as expected (especially since it was so close)

Comment: Good point. I had forgotten the OP used `reduce` when I posted my comment. I see I misspoke about replacing `item` with `(key, value)`; it should be `(key1, key2, value)` or somesuch.